# Devexpress filter editor : Use ArrayList as data for columns

Tags: arraylist, filter, devexpress, popupmenu

I have an ArrayList that contains records which I need to display in the Devexpress filter editor as fields/columns. How can I use this ArrayList in the OnFilterControlPopupMenuShowing(object sender, PopupMenuShowingEventArgs e) function?

Comment: Maybe this will be of use: [link](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q513217)

Answer (score 0):

This worked:
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList(list1.Keys);
        foreach (string s in list) {
          filterControl1.FilterColumns.Add(new UnboundFilterColumn(s, s, typeof(string), new RepositoryItemTextEdit(), FilterColumnClauseClass.String));
            }